# can't stop loop with user input python turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, turtle-graphics

here's my code i'm using the python turtle package:

```py
#setup
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
obj = turtle.Turtle()
go = True


def restart(x, y, go = go):
    go = False
    print(go)
wn.onscreenclick(restart)
wn.listen()

#main loop
while go:
    wn.update()
    obj.forward(0.1)

print("game ended")
```

when i click the screen it should stop do the code after.
the loop won't stop and it won't say "game ended"
i am not sure why.

I need help.
thanks!

Comment: Consider accepting an answer that will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining a local variable `go` in your `restart` function, when you set it to `False` you are only changing the local variable's value not the `go` variable from the outer scope

```
def restart(x, y, go=go):  # This keyword argument is creating a local variable
```

Just remove the argument and you will then modify the correct variable

```
def restart(x, y):
    go = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with your global variable issue, that @IainShelvington points out, I recommend you redesign your program to use turtle timer events:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def restart(x, y):
    global running
    running = False

def move():
    if running:
        turtle.forward(0.1)
        screen.ontimer(move)
    else:
        screen.bye()

turtle = Turtle()

screen = Screen()
screen.onscreenclick(restart)

running = True

move()

screen.mainloop()

print("game ended")
```